# How to ignore new fields for an object model with Firebase 1.0.2

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm using the last version [at the moment](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-quickstart.html) of Firebase dependency, which is 1.0.2 and I'm having problems into getting my pojos parsed correctly.

The thing is, at any time the schema can changed but I don't want my app to crash with this:

> D/AndroidRuntime(14097): Shutting down VM W/dalvikvm(14097):
>   threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a451f8)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(14097): com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed
>   to bounce to type E/AndroidRuntime(14097):    at
>   com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:213)

Looking into the dependency tree I get that Firebase is using Jackson mapper 1.9.7, so the annotation `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true")` is not an option. Moreover, the object mapper is wrapped into this Firebase object so I can't configure the `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property (`DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` for Jackson 1.9 and before).

Is there any way to set this property, either as a class-level annotation or configuring the mapper or any other mechanism whatsoever?

The best solution would be that Firebase 1.0.3 started using Jackson 2.0, but don't know if this is something they care about right now.

Note: I've already thought about excluding the transitive Jackson 1.9.7 dependency and adding Jackson 2.0 so that I can access to this ignoreUnknown feature, but I don't think it is a viable choice since I would be changing the mayor version.

Comment: I've reached out to the Firebase Android SDK developers and it seems like it should be possible to update Jackson to 2.0. Stay tuned for updates!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firebase 1.0.3 was released and now uses Jackson 2.2.2, so annotation `@JsonIgnore` is the way to go.

Edit:
as of now in 2017, Firebase doesn't use Jackson anymore. the correct annotation is [`@Exclude`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude).

Comment: How to do it with the new NEW firebase 9.0.0 that does NOT use jackson anymore?

Comment: I edited the answer a time ago. You need `@Exclude` now or use `transient` in your field.

Answer (score 48):

For those who have moved over to Google's official version of Firebase (As of May 29, 2016), you can use **@Exclude** instead of @JsonIgnore or @JsonProperty. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_java_model_objects_numbered) is the link to their document.

*Example:*

```
public class dataPacket{
    public String data;
    ...
    @Exclude
    public String getData(){return data;}
}
```

Answer (score 36):

**Update:**

As others pointed, annotation `@Exclude` is right way to use it now. But if you use Kotlin that won't work. For Kotlin use

```kotlin
    @Exclude @JvmField 
    var data: String? = nil
    //or
    @set:Exclude @get:Exclude 
    var data: String? = nil
```

Because annotation can be applied only for generated fields and not to properties.

**Old answer:**

I'm coming to Firebase from GSON were I used transient keyword. And that works with Firebase too

```
public transient String data;
```

Answer (score 15):

As the accepted answer states, Firebase now uses Jackson, so you can annotate the desired methods you wish to ignore with

> @JsonIgnore

### Edit:

Firebase changed everything. Woot. Now use this instead:

> @Exclude

Comment: By the time I asked this question, Firebase used an old version (1.9.7) of Jackson with didn't support @JsonIgnore. Check the accepted answer.