# firebase: InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class java.util.TimeZone

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, instantiationexception

I try to parse a List of `EventPojo`-classes from a firebase DB like this:

```
GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, EventPojo>> tEvents = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, EventPojo>>() {};
HashMap<String, EventPojo> events = dataSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.eventsNodeName)).getValue(tEvents);
```

In `EventPojo` I have a `GregorianCalender`:

```
public class EventPojo implements Comparable<EventPojo>{

    GregorianCalendar date;
...
```

When I try to get the HashMap from the DB, I get an `InstantiationException`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: Can't instantiate abstract class java.util.TimeZone
```

Why is firebase trying to instatiate `TimeZone` and not `GregorianCalender`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database only stores JSON types. There is no way to serialize/deserialize a `GregorianCalendar` (or `TimeZone`) without writing custom code.

My typical approach is to have a property of the JSON type (for example, a `Long` to store the timestamp), and then have a getter that returns the type that the app works with (so a `GregorianCalendar` in your case). To make sure Firebase doesn't try to serialize the `GregorianCalendar` method, mark it as [`@Exclude`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) (also see: [How to ignore new fields for an object model with Firebase 1.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125697/how-to-ignore-new-fields-for-an-object-model-with-firebase-1-0-2) for some examples of this).

So:

```
public class EventPojo implements Comparable<EventPojo>{
    public Long timestamp

    @Exclude
    public GregorianCalendar getDate() {
      ...
    }
    @Exclude
    public void getDate(GregorianCalendar date) {
      ...
    }

    ...
```

With this, Firebase will see the `timestamp` field and read it from and write it to the database, while your code just interacts with `getDate()` and `setDate()`.